# How to insert a formula in studio

Tags: r

How can I insert this formula in R studio and generate an output when `m=10`. The formula is `2[(m-1 choose m-1)+ (m choose m-1) until+(2m-2 choose m-1)]`.

Comment: The question is unclear. What exactly do you want to have output? 
Please provide data/output an example, clarifying your question.
Additionally please use the formula environment by pressing ctrl + k while marking code, for easier reading.

Comment: you can use the nChooseK function in R - please provide more info it is unclear!

Comment: What do you mean by "until" there? As the other commenters say, if you want someone to help you, you will need to be more precise about what you need help with.

Comment: Rstudio is an IDE not a language, why do you mention it ?

Comment: Basically I am trying use this formula to find the number if different outcomes in a 2-team basketball playoff that ends when team wins m game

Comment: and I am asked to use R to solve this problem.

Comment: You are being asked by who?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m <- 10
group_size <- seq(m-1, 2*m - 2, by = 1)
# [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
2 * sum(choose(group_size, m-1))
# [1] 184756
```